# Slow response time when coming back to a page hosted under IIS7

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp.net

I have deployed an ASP.NET MVC site under IIS7 on a local Windows Server 2008. The site works well, although I find the init time a bit long. I'm seated locally on this machine. If I browse the web site a bit and then leave for some time (let's say 30 or 60 minutes), when back and I click on a link, it takes again a long time to render the response. Then the next links are ok.

I don't know a lot about IIS yet, but I checked the recycle time in the IIS config and it's set to 29 hours, so I guess the answer is not there.

Also, my site uses [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) and I checked that there was nothing wrong in the log.

Where should I check next ? What can cause that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does sound like the worker process is shutting down because it's idle.  In the Application Pool you might look at the Advanced Settings / Process Model / Idle Time-Out.  By default this is 20 minutes. I.e. it will shut down after 20 mins if it's Idle.

The Recycle time is effectively the maximum time a process is allowed run when it is continually busy before being restarted.

Comment: I would just like to point out that the Idle Time-Out can be inherited. I was looking at my Outlook Web Access App and it had idle-timeout of 0 but the ASP.Net timeout was 20. When I changed that, it also fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is another reason why your application pool recycles (if it recycles.) You could check the Windows application event log, to find out if in that time period a IIS event like this one is looged:

> 5195: A worker process with process id
>   of '%1' serving application pool '%2'
>   was shut down due to inactivity.  The
>   system is under high load and has
>   decreased the idle timeout of this
>   worker process to '%4' minutes from
>   its original '%3' minutes.  A new
>   worker process will be started when
>   needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dynamicIdleThreshold setting.  Here are some [details](http://blogs.iis.net/mukhtard/archive/2009/04/21/webhosting-performance-tunings-for-iis7.aspx).

Comment: well, I am on a local test machine here, not in a web hosting environment. From what I see, dynamicIdleThreshold is not setup here.